# How To Adjust Font Size To Fill A Fixed Height Table Cell In iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I am creating a PDF from iTextSharp for printing. I have varible length text that I would like to always be in the maximum font size to fill a fixed height table cell without wrapping out of sight. How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to start by being able to measure the width of your text in the font that you have chosen.  From the iTextSharp documentation:

> **Measuring text**
>
> Sometimes it's necessary to know the length of a
>   certain piece of text. If you have
>   created a BaseFont object, you can use
>   the method: 
>   public float getWidthPoint(String text, float
>   fontSize); So if you are using some
>   barcode font with size 36 as in the
>   previous example and you want to know
>   how much space you need on the line to
>   print this barcode, you just do:
>   getWidthPoint("0123456789", 36f). The
>   result is the width in points. There
>   are 72 points in 1 inch. So if you
>   have a result of 252 points (as in
>   example 8), you can convert this to
>   inches and centimeters like this: 252
>   / 72 = 3.5 inch * 2.54 = 8.89 cm

This will get you the width of your string with whatever font you have chosen as a default.  You can then use the fixed width of your table cell to find the proper font size to fill the width of your cell without wrapping.

```
textWidth = getWidthPoint("sample text", originalFontHeight)
newFontHeight = (cellWidth / textWidth ) * originalFontHeight
```

Then just make sure that the new font's height (which is already given in points by the font size) does not exceed the height of your table cell.

Comment: getWidthPoint does not exist in iText 8 anymore, the best approach i could find is to get the font and use its width. Which in my opinion is very stupid that they removed this function. If anyone has a better method of getting this please do let me know.