# identifying if text wrapped in a paragraph/cell

Tags: .net, vb.net, itext

I have fully-justified text Chunk (string of varying lengths) followed by a Chunk containing a DottedLineSeparator object. What I am needing to know is if the string of varying length wraps to a second line (theoretically it *could* wrap to a 3rd line but it's very unlikely).

I am familiar with using the GetWidthPoint() method (I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087966/how-to-adjust-font-size-to-fill-a-fixed-height-table-cell-in-itextsharp/2089662#2089662)) on a Chunk object, which is what I am using; but it doesn't work with 100% accuracy I believe due to the full-justification of the text... meaning the spaces may vary in actual width.

What I was hoping was there would be some way to determine the height of the Paragraph containing these two chunks, or the PdfPCell object with which I am using .AddElement() to add the Paragraph object, or even for that matter the PdfPTable object which I add the PdfPCell object to. I do know I can get the height of the table **after** I write the PdfPTable object to the document (using .TotalHeight). It is confusing because I can call cell.GetMaxHeight() but it always returns 8.75... no matter if the text is long enough to wrap or not!

Unfortunately, I have a need to know what the height is for the 1st cell before I can generate content for the remaining cells - which is the dilemma.

Any ideas/pointers/guidance?

Here's some code to illustrate:

```
Dim c As PdfPCell
Dim t As PdfPTable
Dim p As Paragraph
Dim textWrapsAround As Boolean = False
Dim amendedTextWrapsAround As Boolean = False

t = New PdfPTable(3)
t.SetWidths({40, 12, 12})
t.WidthPercentage = 95.0F
t.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER

p = New Paragraph("", DEFAULTFONT)
p.SetLeading(0.5F, 1.0F)
c = New PdfPCell() With {.Border = 0}
c.MinimumHeight = PdfDocument.LineHeightPts

p.Add(New Chunk(name.Trim(), DEFAULTFONT)) 
p.Add(New Chunk(leaderLine))
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED


If p.Chunks(0).GetWidthPoint >= 216 Then textWrapsAround = True


c.AddElement(p)
c.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED
c.PaddingTop = 0
t.SetExtendLastRow(True, False)
t.AddCell(c)

c = emitPdfColumnCell(col1, lFormat, textWrapsAround)
c.MinimumHeight = PdfDocument.LineHeightPts
c.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
c.PaddingTop = If(textWrapsAround AndAlso col2.Contains(vbCrLf), top_padding, 0)
t.SetExtendLastRow(True, False)
t.AddCell(c)

c = emitPdfColumnCell(col2, lFormat, textWrapsAround)
c.MinimumHeight = PdfDocument.LineHeightPts
c.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
c.PaddingTop = If(textWrapsAround AndAlso col2.Contains(vbCrLf), top_padding, 0)
t.SetExtendLastRow(True, False)
t.AddCell(c)

t.KeepTogether = True
pdf_doc.Add(t)
```

Comment: even now I thought maybe if I didn't have the paragraph and cell HorizontalAlignment set to Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED, it might work but it doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way... it's 100% a hack and I probably should switch from using a Table to a ColumnText, since that's how I'm determining how many lines *but*... here's the solution:

```
'returns # of lines 
Private Function CheckParagraphTextWrap(ByVal p As Paragraph) As Integer

    Dim ct As New ColumnText(Me.pdf_writer.DirectContent)
    ct.SetIndent(2.0F, True)
    ct.RightIndent = 1.5F
    Dim show As Boolean = False
    Dim x1, x2, y1, y2 As Double
    Dim phrase As New Phrase()
    phrase.AddAll(p.Chunks)
    'hard-coded to match the EXACT width of the cell... this is essential and
    x1 = 104.25 : y1 = 580 : x2 = 320.72 : y2 = 620
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(phrase, x1, y1, x2, y2, 1.0F, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED)
    ct.SetLeading(0.5F, 1.0F) 'also has to match what was being done for the cell
    ct.Go(Not show) 'simulate mode
    Return ct.LinesWritten

End Function
```

I call this function for each paragraph being added to a cell within a table; it's needed because I have to make accommodations to the other cells in the table after this one. Clunky but it works (at least so far) 100% of the time. My prior methodology only worked about 95% of the time :)